# Polygonal sides when interior angle relationship is given

Tags: geometry

The difference between any two consecutive interior angles of a polygon is 5°. The smallest angle is 120°. Find the number of sides. I know that the sum of interior angles of a polygon is $(n-2)\cdot180$ degrees. I don't know how to connect the relationship

Comment: Because it is a polygon, the largest angle must be consecutive to the smallest. Does that also mean largest – smallest $= 5^0?$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

**7**.

Cannot be 6: the average angle then is $720^\circ/6=120^\circ=\min$, so the $5^\circ$ difference condition is violated.

7: $120+125+130+135+135+130+125=900$  - correct!

More than 7: Consider external angles instead. Their sum is $360^\circ$. The largest is $60^\circ$. This leaves $300^\circ$. At least two are $55^\circ$ (adjacent to the largest). This leaves $190^\circ$. At least two are $50^\circ$. This leaves $90^\circ$. Can you take the last step?